# Manim video animation does not work in rendered Quarto blog

Tags: python, jupyter, quarto, manim

I am trying out Manim in my quarto blog file, however, even though the same code renders in a jupyter notebook (ipynb) it does not render in my rendered quarto html. I believe there is something wrong with the media path to the video, however, it does not seem to auto put the video in the html.

Below is my qmd file:

````
---
title: "manim"
format: html
---

# Manimce test

first chunk

```{python}
from manim import *

config.media_width = "75%"
config.verbosity = "WARNING"
```

second chunk
```{python}
%%manim -qm CircleToSquare

class CircleToSquare(Scene):
def construct(self):
blue_circle = Circle(color=BLUE, fill_opacity=0.5)
green_square = Square(color=GREEN, fill_opacity=0.8)
self.play(Create(blue_circle))
self.wait()

        self.play(Transform(blue_circle, green_square))
        self.wait()

```
````

Here is a similar .ipynb file that works:

````
(first chunk)
```
from manim import *
config.media_width = "75%" config.verbosity = "WARNING"
```

(second chunk)
```

%%manim -qm CircleToSquare

class CircleToSquare(Scene):
def construct(self):
blue_circle = Circle(color=BLUE, fill_opacity=0.5)
green_square = Square(color=GREEN, fill_opacity=0.8)
self.play(Create(blue_circle))
self.wait()
self.play(Transform(blue_circle, green_square))
self.wait()

```
````

The above code renders the video in the ipynb file.

When I press render HTML, I get this in the console:

```
Starting python3 kernel...Done

Executing 'manim1.ipynb' Cell 1/2...Done Cell 2/2...Done

[2/2] index.qmd WARNING: File C:\Users\Aj\Documents\GitHub\portfolio\posts\linalg\tempw1.ipynb in the listing 'listing' contains no metadata.

Output created: ....\docs\posts\linalg\manim1.html

Terminating existing preview server....DONE

Preparing to preview

Watching files for changes Browse at http://localhost:7543/posts/linalg/manim1.html GET: /posts/linalg/manim1.html /posts/linalg/media/jupyter/CircleToSquare@2023-04-05@15-47-01.mp4 (404: Not Found)
```

The media folder seems to have the video, however, when it renders, it does not automatically pull from the correct place:

[Folders with the rendered video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1n3i.png)

Which probably is the root of the problem, I just don't know how to solve this

[My ipynb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwMhQ.png)

[My quarto file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ASgJ.png)

The specs I am using are the following:

- Python 3.10.7
- Jupyter: 4.11.1
- Kernels: python3
- `pip show manim` => Name: manim Version: 0.17.2
- `ffmpeg --version` => ffmpeg version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev
- `choco --version` => 1.3.1

I am generally familiar with Quarto, and I guess I am familiar enough with manim to render something in an ipynb, however, I am not sure how to approach this

Comment: `...(backslashes added for markdown aesthetic)`  ... you might want to improve the question editing.

Comment: I will try to work on that, I was struggling to include the backticks without stackoverflow interpreting it as another code chunk. If you have any suggestions on how to do this in the file, I would be grateful. I am relatively new to this.